# How is minimum priority thread getting executed before maximum priority thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

While executing this code, sometimes I notice that the thread with minimum priority is getting executed before the thread with maximum priority. Can anyone help me understand what's going on here?

```
class Test implements Runnable 
{
    public void run()
    {
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}
class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(test);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(test);

        t1.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        t1.setName("Max priority thread");

        t2.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        t2.setName("Min priority thread");

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Sometimes, I'm getting the output as

```
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Min priority thread
```

and sometimes as

```
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Max priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
Min priority thread
```

Logically, the thread with maximum priority should start first. But sometimes it is not happening. If this is unavoidable, then how to make sure that the thread with maximum priority will always start first?

Comment: Threads need not be executed based on their priority. Ultimately its the OS which decides when to execute which thread. The priority you give is just a suggestion..

Comment: i think the thread priority is just a recommendation to the underlying OS. there is no guarantee to which thread will actually get executed first.

Comment: @TheLostMind: Then is there any way or algorithm which will make sure that a particular thread will get executed first?

Comment: @NullPointer - I don't think so..

Comment: You could make the low priority thread wait for a synchronization object that the high priority thread signals but we probably could help you better if you told us your use case. When using multiple threads, it rarely if ever should matter in what order they get executed. If it does, you don't need threads.

Comment: The test with 5 iterations is meaningless. If you want to check the impact of thread priority then run the same code in both threads for a prolonged period of time and compare the amount of actual work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Priorities are just a suggestion to the scheduler. The only way to *guarantee* that one particular thread executes before another is to do it yourself with an appropriate concurrency mechanism such as a [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

Comment: Didn't know about `CountDownLatch`. This really helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

try using **ExecutorService** or **ForkJoinPool** in order to better control on your threads.

and may this will help you :

```
java.util.List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    threads.add(i, new Thread());
}
for(Thread thread : threads){
    thread.start();
    thread.wait(10);
}
```

EDIT: example for **ForkJoinPool**:

```
    public void start() {
        final int parallelism = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        final ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(parallelism);
        final List<ForkJoinTask<Thread>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            tasks.add(i, newTask(forkJoinPool, i));
            tasks.get(i).invoke().start();
        }
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
    }

    private ForkJoinTask<Thread> newTask(final ForkJoinPool pool, final int i) {
        return pool.submit(() -> new Thread(() -> {
            System.out.println("no " + i);
            Thread.sleep(50);
        })).fork();
    }
```

and the output:

```
no 0
no 1
no 2
no 3
no 4
no 5
no 6
no 7
no 8
no 9
no 10
no 12
no 11
no 13
no 14
no 15
no 16
no 17
no 18
no 19
no 20
no 21
no 22
no 23
no 24
no 25
no 26
no 27
no 28
no 29
no 30
no 31
no 32
no 34
no 37
no 38
no 36
no 33
no 35
no 40
no 39
no 41
no 42
no 43
no 44
no 45
no 46
no 47
no 48
no 49
no 50
no 51
no 52
no 53
no 54
no 55
no 56
no 57
no 58
no 59
no 61
no 60
no 62
no 63
no 64
no 65
no 66
no 67
no 69
no 68
no 70
no 72
no 71
no 73
no 74
no 75
no 76
no 78
no 77
no 79
no 80
no 81
no 82
no 84
no 83
no 85
no 86
no 87
no 88
no 89
no 90
no 91
no 92
no 93
no 94
no 96
no 95
no 97
no 98
no 99
```

Comment: @NullPointer was this helpful?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for suggesting one more way.